# How to make a hole in a cylinder side?

Tags: modeling

[image: ****]

i wanted to make eyes similiar to robot in image.I tried intersect face with another cylinder but while adding sub surface modifier the mesh distorts

Comment: Look into "crease edge" This prevents Subsurface modifier from distorting hard edges  
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html?highlight=edge%20crease